# Display elements after one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say a group of divs like this:

```
<div class="foo" data-index="1">bar one</div>
<div class="foo hidden" data-index="3">bar three</div>
<div class="foo hidden" data-index="4">bar four</div>
<div class="foo hidden" data-index="2">bar two</div>
```

How do I remove the hidden class on the next index element after one has been clicked. So basically there's a visible div, then the user clicks and the next div appears, and so on.

I can loop through them easy enough but I can't get the click delay down.

```
var obj;

obj = $("div[data-index]").sort(function(a, b) {
  $(a).data("index") - $(b).data("index");
});

$.each(obj, function() {
  console.log($(this).data('index'));
  //WAIT FOR A CLICK ON THIS
  $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

... but I'd like to pause on each pass and wait for the user to click.

BONUS: adding an additional class ("last") on the last item in the obj is my next challenge.:)

Comment: So clicking div with index=1 then reveals index=2?

Comment: Yep, basically. The only unknown is how many divs there will be in total.

Comment: So you're clicking divs right? And they can be in any order, perhaps random.

Comment: They need to appear in the order of data-index when clicking through them, but won't be in order in the dom. That's why I need to sort first.

Comment: So visually do they need to be reordered?

Comment: Does it need to wrap around to 1 when it reaches the end?

Comment: I won't be moving the items around the dom. I just need to toggle the classes in a specific order -- after a click. It's possible that  one item might be in the footer and the next in the header, etc.

Comment: @Barmar it would be nice if ended on the last one. But I don't won't to be greedy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're creating some type of DOM hide and seek game.  I think below will work, and it does the bonus as well.

```
$('.foo').click(function(event)
{
    var target = $(event.target);
    var index = target.data('index');

    var nextDiv = $('[data-index="' + (index + 1) + '"]');
    var lastDiv = $('[data-index="' + (index + 2) + '"]');

    nextDiv.removeClass('hidden');

    if(lastDiv.length === 0)
    {
        nextDiv.addClass('last');
    }
});
```

Checkout the jsFiddle below and let me know if that works for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/VW5x9/

Comment: That's awesome. Much better. The fiddle throws an error in Safari: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-index="2"` , but the proof of concept is fine and works in Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops missed a ] on the selector. Updated, give her a try now.

Comment: Interesting concept BTW

Comment: It's actually for a walkthrough for an app. I'm not a big fan of those, but I wanted to something that was flexible. So basically I'll have divs with a data-index and data-text and will wrap the data-text in popups attached to the elements. It would work something like this but much simpler. http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

Comment: Damn thats a hot plugin!

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to build on cgatian's answer because I was also a interested in the concept. I ended up making two different forks from his jsfiddle. The [first one](http://jsfiddle.net/q69Nx/) stores the current data-index in a global variable and increments it each time it gets clicked. It's not too impressive and possibly even worse than the original answer. My second attempt was much more successful however. Here is the code for the second attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = $("[data-index]");
    elements.splice(0, 1);
    elements.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).attr("data-index") - $(b).attr("data-index");
    });

    $(".foo").click(function (event) {
        $(elements.splice(0, 1)).removeClass("hidden").addClass(elements.length == 0 ? "last" : "");
    });
});
```

It stores all the elements in a global variable and then sorts them from least to highest data-index. This is great because it provides lots of flexibility. It doesn't matter what is the first or last data-index, and it doesn't even matter if you skip some numbers in between. On top of that you can easily change the order to go in reverse by changing a to b and b to a in the sort function, which should give a very slight speed boost. You also don't have to find any elements when you click. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YuSAp/) for the second one.